# Where should I edit woocommerce to change description part?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, custom-wordpress-pages

I have wordpress woocomere website. I'v already change title part in

```
woocommerce/single-product/title.php
```

What file should I edit to change section right after it? Or can u give any docs about woocomerece including sequencing.

Comment: generally you don't need to those files. There are hooks to control those. Can you describe your problem a bit more ? like.... After which content you want what like that.... if with screenshot, will be far better.

Comment: Can u give a **gide or article or video lesson** how to use those **hooks** ?

Comment: woocommerce documentation is the best place for that documentation


And here is one article with example -

http://www.mingocommerce.com/move-product-title-above-the-thumbnail-in-product-page/

Product single page hooks you can see in this article (with positions) -
https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-visual-hook-guide-single-product-page/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change woocommerce description part from:-
woocommerce/templates/single-product/tabs/description.php

```
<?php the_content(); ?>  //for description.
```

Comment: but  woocommerce/templates/single-product/tabs/description.php not gos right after woocommerce/single-product/title.php, maybe some other file?

Comment: What section you have after. woocommerce/single-product/title.php

Comment: I think the file  I was looking for is the one you recomend to me.